# Trigger action from the Main menu

Tags: swiftui

The application file:

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .commands {
            MenuLine_Help_Examples()
        }
    }
    fileprivate func MenuLine_Help_Examples() -> CommandGroup<Button<Text>> {
        CommandGroup(after: CommandGroupPlacement.help) {
            Button("Add Example") {
                createExample()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `createExample()` adds some data to the storage. However, added data is not visible in the UI. If I restart the application, data appears. I understand why, that is OK.

How can I trigger reload/refresh of the app? My guess is to move `createExample` in some inner view and try to trigger it via `StateObject` passed as environment Object.

EDIT: the problem with my attempt was that I can not "catch" the change. I used `onChange()` on `@EnvironmentObject`, and it was never triggered.

But I am still failing.

Comment: Your idea sounds like a good one -- can you show your attempt?

Comment: @jnpdx just edited. in short, i was unable to "catch" the change action. I see that the state of the environment object changes, but I could not run any action of my on that change.

Comment: You don't use `onChange` on an `EnvironmentObject` -- you can use `onReceive` for a `@Published` property, though. It would help to see what you've tried to provide a solution.

Comment: It worked. onReceive is the thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use e.g.

```swift
class AddExampleModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var state: Int = 0

    func toggle() {
        state += 1
    }

    func reset() {
        state = 0
    }
}
```

then in main:

```swift
@StateObject var addExample = AddExampleModel()
```

and then in the view:

```swift
@EnvironmentObject var addExample: AddExampleModel
...
.onReceive([addExample.state].publisher.first()) { value in
   if (value > 0) {
     createExample()
     selectExample()
     addExample.reset()
     }
}
```